# Cannot parse flag with argument in argp.h

Tags: c, argp

I'm learning C, and got stuck doing cli parsing with `<argp.h>`. I want to specify path with `-p, --path` flags, so I did this:

```
#include "treesome.h"
#include <argp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char *argp_program_version =
    "treesome-build 0.2";


static char doc[] =
    "Treesome -- filesystem tree-like output\
\v Tree will show easy to eyeball directory structure";

static char args_doc[] = "";

static struct argp_option options[] = {
{0,0,0,0, "Output view" },
{"all", 'a', 0, 0, "produce verbose output with all the content"},
{"dereference", 'd', 0, 0, "dereferences soft links"},
{"path", 'p', 0, OPTION_ARG_OPTIONAL, "specify path for tree root"},
{ 0 }
};

struct arguments {
    int all, derefence, is_path;
    char *path;
};

static error_t parse_opts(int key, char *arg, struct argp_state *state) {
    struct arguments *arguments = state->input;

    switch (key) {
        case 'a':
            arguments->all = 1;
            break;
        case 'd':
            arguments->derefence = 1;
            break;
        case 'p':
            arguments->is_path = 1;
            break;
        case ARGP_KEY_ARG:
            if (state->arg_num == 0)
                break;
            if (arguments->is_path == 1)
                arguments->path = arg;
            break;
        default:
            return ARGP_ERR_UNKNOWN;
    }
    return 0;
};

static struct argp argp = {
options,
parse_opts,
args_doc,
doc
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct arguments arguments;

    arguments.all = 0;
    arguments.derefence = 0;
    arguments.path = ".";

    argp_parse(&argp, argc, argv, 0, 0, &arguments);
    printf("Called with args: \n");
    printf("%d for all\n", arguments.all);
    printf("%d for dereference\n", arguments.derefence);
    printf("%s for path\n\n", arguments.path);
    return treesome(arguments.path);
};
```

and typing `./tree -p /home/floatfoo/` I got that path is always default. What might be a problem? I dont quite understand what for `ARGP_KEY_ARG` and `ARGP_KEY_ARGS` are used for

Comment: Please post a full [MCVE]. Where is `#include <argp.h>` and `main`? How is `argp` struct defined? `I got that path` How do you "get that" - what value do you print (do you print it?) and how? If you are using `argp.h`, are you calling `argp_parse`? How and where is `parse_opts` used? Is it used by argp at all? Where is the default for "path" defined and how is it used? Don't you want just `case 'p': arguments->path = arg`?

Comment: @KamilCuk I've tried `case 'p': arguments->path = arg`. Just keep getting `Too many arguments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After *removing treesome* your option does not take an argument:

> ```
> {"path", 'p', 0, OPTION_ARG_OPTIONAL, "specify path for tree root"},
>              ^^^
>
> ./a.out --help
>      -p, --path                 specify path for tree root
> ```

You have to take the option:

```
 {"path", 'p', "path", OPTION_ARG_OPTIONAL, "specify path for tree root"},

 ./a.out --help
     -p, --path[=path]          specify path for tree root
```

In which case *only the long* form takes the option.

```
./a.out -p smth      -> too many arguments
./a.out --path=smth  -> ok
```

Remove `OPTION_ARG_OPTIONAL` if you want `-p` to take arg. And also set your path and remove the KEY_ARG case.  It's just:

```
static error_t parse_opts(int key, char *arg, struct argp_state *state) {
    struct arguments *arguments = state->input;

    switch (key) {
        case 'a':
            arguments->all = 1;
            break;
        case 'd':
            arguments->derefence = 1;
            break;
        case 'p':
            arguments->path = arg;
            break;
        default:
            return ARGP_ERR_UNKNOWN;
    }
    return 0;
};
```